# Is promise concept available in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, es6-promise, method-chaining

I'm Just wondering, Is there a chaining concept in ruby.
I wanted to execute series of async tasks or methods one after the other. Is it possible?

Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: Ruby is inherently synchronous. So, no, the 'promise concept' (I assume you're referring to the JS promise concept), is not 'available' in ruby. Is it possible to have a series of asynchronous tasks execute in a specified order with each task executing only when the previous task is completed? Yes.

Comment: Good morning Jvillian, Thanks a lot . Can you pl. help me understand, how is it possible to execute a chain of asnc tasks in ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to create a process class, something like:

```
class MyProcess

  PROCESS_STEPS = %w(
    step_one
    step_two
    step_three
  )

  class << self 

    def next_step
      new.next_step
    end

  end # Class Methods

  #======================================================================
  # Instance Methods
  #======================================================================

    def next_step
      PROCESS_STEPS.each do |process_step|
        send(process_step) if send("do_#{process_step}?")
      end
    end

    def step_one
      # execute step one task
    end

    def do_step_one?
      # some logic
    end

    def step_two
      # execute step two task
    end

    def do_step_two?
      # some logic
    end

    def step_three
      # execute step three task
    end

    def do_step_three?
      # some logic
    end

end
```

You would probably put that in:

```
app 
 |- processes
 |   |- my_process.rb
```

Then, at the end of each task, do something like:

```
MyProcess.next_step
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript, where Promises were first introduced, is also synchronous, promises being an abstraction over callbacks in the strictest sense

There are concurrency libraries for Ruby, some of which capture the spirit of Promises to a certain extent, a google search for `promise.rb` yields some promising results:

https://github.com/lgierth/promise.rb
https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby

Perhaps these are not idiomatic ruby, but they do offer some useful paradigms

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can tell, `promise.rb` is the most commonly used gem for an async mechanism adhering to the js Promise/A+ standard.

This article does a decent job of introducing it: https://medium.com/@gauravbasti2006/lets-keep-our-promise-in-ruby-e45925182fdc

Answer (score 0):

[concurrent-ruby](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby) is most widely used to implement concurrency related features like promises, similar to other widely used languages. The documentation is pretty straightforward as well:
https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby/blob/master/docs-source/promises.in.md

For chaining asynchronous tasks you can use the following:
https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby/blob/master/docs-source/promises.in.md#chaining